# Is $x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+i\left(y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$ an analytic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

How can I find out wheter the function below is an analytical function or not?

$$x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+i\left(y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

I found a solution with Cauchy-Riemann equations. However, I don't know that yet. How do I find out without Cauchy-Riemann?

Comment: You can add equations to your question using LaTeX: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117 Also, it's good to show your working out.

Comment: In general, are you able to compute the limit as $v\to a$ of a function $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ ?

Comment: With $z=x+iy$, your function is $z+\dfrac1z$ (because $\dfrac{\bar z}{|z|^2}=\dfrac{\bar z}{z\bar z}=\dfrac1z$)

Comment: Why does your third sentence contradict the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Well,with $z=x+iy$,

$$x+iy=z \quad \text{ and } \quad \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}=\frac{1}{z},$$

So your function is $$f(z) = z+\frac{1}{z}.$$

Your function, $f(z)$, is holomorphic and thus analytic everywhere other than at the origin: $$z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus {0}.$$

One reason is because sums, differences, products, and quotients (other than when the denominator is zero) of holomorphic functions are holomorphic.

Comment: Oh, I see that this has already been answered in the comments.  There's your answer.

Comment: thanks u so much !!!

Comment: You  are welcome